# Python 2.5: ElementTree and UML in XML

Tags: python, elementtree, python-2.5

I'm working with an XML file which represent an UML model. Here is an example of what it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMI xmi.version="1.1" xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML13">
 <XMI.content>
  <UML:Model name="Model" xmi.id="_0">
   <UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
    <UML:Package name="Standard" xmi.id="_5">
     </UML:Package>
   </UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
   </UML:Model>
 </XMI.content>
</XMI>
```

It is a Rhapsody import format.

I want to modify this XML file by using ElementTree in Python 2.5.

I have at least one problem but I found 2 consequences, here they are:

With this simple code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('source.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
tree.write('output.xml')
```

The output is: (and I don't wanted any change)

```
<XMI xmi.version="1.1">
   <XMI.content>
      <ns0:Model name="FPLN_Model" xmi.id="_0" xmlns:ns0="omg.org/UML13">
         <ns0:Namespace.ownedElement>
            <ns0:Package name="Standard" xmi.id="_5">
            </ns0:Package>
         </ns0:Namespace.ownedElement>
      </ns0:Model>
   </XMI.content>
</XMI>
```

I searched about this problem and I found a topic on stackoverflow that said to add

```
ET.register_namespace("UML", "omg.org/UML13")
```

But an error occur:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register_namespace'
```

The second consequence is that with a code like the following:

```
for Package_Node in Temp_Node.find('UML:Package'):
```

I get the error: `SyntaxError: expected path separator (:)`

Have someone an idea to help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register_namespace` is [only available since Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace)

There might be another way to preserve namespaces with ElementTree in 2.5, but I'm not aware of it.

Alternatively, you could try another parsing library. [lxml](http://lxml.de/) preserves namespaces and its API is compatible with ElementTree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally found another solution, the company in which I'm doing my internship has developed and alternative to modify XML files so I will use it.

Answer (score 1):

see this page:http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm

## ElementTree 1.3 (Python 2.7)

ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)

## ElementTree 1.2 (Python 2.5)

ET._namespace_map[uri] = prefix